# How does Stack Exchange implement its login system?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, login

Is the Stack Exchange login system supported by a service like [RPX](http://www.janrain.com/products/engage), or is it just a custom development based on well-known frameworks for each federated login (e.g. dotnetopenauth, facebook connect)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenID and OAuth. (Facebook now supports OAuth 2.0)